# Man who went through blue, yellow and red phases of super powers

Tags: story-identification, tv

What TV series was this? It was probably later 1980s, the main characters was genetically modified or perhaps created in a lab. What I remember most clearly was his super power. Normally, "condition blue" he was smarter, faster and stronger than most humans.

But then, under a certain condition (which I think had to do with heating his brain), he went to condition yellow where his powers were dramatically increased. Finally, he could go to condition red for short periods, which was very dangerous - his brain would fry or something.

I seem to remember there were three main characters - the male lead I've just described, and a female and older male scientists.

I think it only lasted one series. It was almost certainly a US series. It was a live action series.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I reckon this is [North Star](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091650/), which wasn't a series, it never made it past being a pilot. Greg Evigan starred as Major Jack North, an astronaut who during a spacewalk, looks directly at the sun (there may have been some [Applied Phlebotinum](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AppliedPhlebotinum) involved). On returning to Earth, he discovers he possesses superpowers when his eyes are exposed to sunlight (or possibly UV radiation). His powers, as you say, stepped up in stages, blue, yellow and red. I distinctly remember the line 'and my IQ increased to 1000' during the blue stage, however the script made great play of the fact that overexposure during the red stage would kill him.

Comment: You did well to find this! Even Google lets me down here, despite trying this as a title. Unless I get a different answer soon, I will accept this one, thanks!

Comment: @Wikis I only saw it once and it was about 25 years ago, however I have to confess there was a similar story-id question in [SFX](http://www.sfx.co.uk/) a couple of years ago...

Comment: Awesome memory, thanks!

Comment: The [IMDB reviews](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091650/reviews) have more details, which confirm that this is definitely the right answer.

Comment: Just watched pilot episode of northstar through google/you tube 1986 it was released but am sure there is more than the pilot as somewhere he read in blue colour how bto fly a helicopter